# ES6 import in for-of-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, import, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to import and export multiple files using for-of-loop (or another loop) in ES6?

```
const moduleNames = ['NumberUtils', 'StringUtils', 'ArrayUtils', 'MyModule', 'AnotherModule', 'BaseModule']

let modules = {}

for (const moduleName of moduleNames) {
    import module from './' + moduleName
    modules.moduleName = module
}

export modules
```

Without loop I have to write:

```
import NumberUtils from './NumberUtils'
import StringUtils from './StringUtils'
import ArrayUtils from './ArrayUtils'
import MyModule from './MyModule'
import AnotherModule from './AnotherModule'
import BaseModule from './BaseModule'

export {
    NumberUtils,
    StringUtils
    ArrayUtils
    MyModule
    AnotherModule
    BaseModule
}
```

Comment: You can do `export {default as NumberUtils} from "./NumberUtils";` FYI, which makes these types of lists easier to maintain. Why is adding one line of code harder than adding an item to an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For multiple import files I found this solution:

```
const files = require.context('../myFolder', true, /(Module|Utils)\.js$/)
```

Comment: It's valid only for Webpack. Not for ES6 in general.

Comment: Also it's not intended for static extraction. As per their warning:
`Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

Comment: sir his asking you to do it with es6 so no `require` keyword can be used

Answer (score 13):

One of main features of ES modules is they can be statically analyzed. For this reason `import` statement follows [strict syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) - so does `export`. A snippet 'without loop' is the way it has to be done.

This allows to figure out module imports and exports exactly in IDEs and tools. This is useful for tree-shaking, for instance.

Answer (score 8):

I think that better and more clear way to do it is to create an index file and then import multiple components in one import.

```
//index.js
import PopUp from './PopUp';
import ToggleSwitch from './ToggleSwitch';

export {
  PopUp,
  ToggleSwitch
};

//app.js

import { PopUp, ToggleSwitch } from './components';
```